Optimizing declaration of symbols implemented in stdlib
I'm creating a static compiled application for an embedded device.
The device has implementation for common std functions like memset/strlen.
In order to reduce the size of the binary I'm compiling without the standard library and linking with the functions defined in a symbols file.
This option pretty much disables optimizations for std functions. Is there a way to tell gcc to treat that functions like the std counterparts?
Thanks in advance!

Add -nostdlib and your library to the gcc link command.

Re “I'm compiling without the standard library”: The library is mostly considered to be the library file containing object code for the standard library routines. Do you mean you are compiling without including headers for the standard library? E.g., your files do not contain #include <string.h>?

Re “This option pretty much disables optimizations for std functions. Is there a way to tell gcc to treat that functions like the std counterparts?”: GCC ordinarily treats the identifiers defined in the library section of the C standard as special functions and automatically optimizes them. This might be disabled with the -fno-builtin switch, by building GCC in a custom way, or if you include a header that defines those identifies with #define statements. Are you doing any of those things? If not, edit the question to show a [mre] demonstrating that optimization is disabled.

"This option pretty much ..." To avoid misunderstandings, what option exactly are you talking about? How do you build your program?

In case your rationale for not using the standard lib is to reduce binary size, then you are doing it wrong. The rationale for writing the functions yourself rather needs to be something like "all libraries must be verified, MISRA C compatible" etc. Personally, I have a stripped down version of the standard lib containing the 50 or so most common functions hand coded, but that's only because in safety-related software, all libraries must be conforming and if you can't do analysis on the library code (because it's an object file etc) then you have to write it yourself.
